# Как авторизоваться на target.com с PHP?

Tags: php, curl, авторизация

Что только не перепробовал что-бы авторизоваться на target.com... - всё четно.

```
    <?php 
  function clrequest($url, $postdata = null, $cookiefile = 'tmp/cookies.txt')
  {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0');

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '192.168.1.104:8887');
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if ($postdata){
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata))                                                                       
    );  
    }

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;

  }
  file_put_contents('tmp/cookies.txt', '');

  $login = "zuckerberg@facebook.com";
  $pass = "dreesunderdress";

  $html = clrequest('https://www.target.com/');
  $html = clrequest('https://www.target.com/gsp/authentications/v1/credential_validations?client_id=ecom-web-1.0.0', '{"username":"'.$login.'","password":"'.$pass.'"}');
  print($html);
?>
```

Ответ на этот код :

```js
{
  "errorCode": "T83072242",
  "errorKey": "_ERR_AUTH_DENIED",
  "errorMessage": "Please correct the following: Error Code T83072242. Your request was not completed. If you need help, you can call us at 800-316-3111.",
  "errorParameters": ""
}
```

А должен

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "errorKey": "_ERR_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST",
    "errorMessage": "Sorry, either your e-mail or password didn't match what we have on file. Try it again?",
    "reason": "_ERR_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST",
    "clientId": "ecom-web-1.0.0"
  }]
}
```

Comment: в условии _if ($postdata){_ первой строкой попробуйте добавить `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: Так мне нужно передавать в json формате , что я и делаю.